# How to pass a Tree as an argument in a function?

Tags: python, class, tree, attributeerror, nonetype

I want to pass a Tree as an argument in a function. In fact, what I want is to pass an object from the class Node as an argument to my function evaluate.

This is the code.

```
PLUS = "+"    
MINUS = "-"
TIMES="*"
DIVIDE="/"

class Node:
    def __init__(self,val=None,left=None,right=None):
        if val != None:
            self.val=val
        else:
            self.val=None
        self.left=left
        self.right=right

def evaluate(root:Node)->int:
    if root.val == PLUS:
        return evaluate(root.left) + evaluate(root.right)
    elif root.val == MINUS:
        return evaluate(root.left) - evaluate(root.right)
    elif root.val == DIVIDE:
        return evaluate(root.left) / evaluate(root.right)
    elif root.val == TIMES:
        return evaluate(root.left) * evaluate(root.right)
    else:
        return root.val
    

tree=Node(TIMES)
tree.left=Node(PLUS)
tree.left.left=Node(3)
tree.left.right=Node(2)
tree.right=Node(PLUS)
tree.right.left=Node(4)
tree.right.left=Node(5)
print(evaluate(tree))
```

But, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lucianomuratore/Desktop/Programming/Python/New_ALGO_&_DATA_STRUCTURES/Trees.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(evaluate(tree))
  File "/Users/lucianomuratore/Desktop/Programming/Python/New_ALGO_&_DATA_STRUCTURES/Trees.py", line 23, in evaluate
    return evaluate(root.left) * evaluate(root.right)
  File "/Users/lucianomuratore/Desktop/Programming/Python/New_ALGO_&_DATA_STRUCTURES/Trees.py", line 17, in evaluate
    return evaluate(root.left) + evaluate(root.right)
  File "/Users/lucianomuratore/Desktop/Programming/Python/New_ALGO_&_DATA_STRUCTURES/Trees.py", line 16, in evaluate
    if root.val == PLUS:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, the code

```
        if val != None:
            self.val=val
        else:
            self.val=None
```

could just be `self.val = val`. Also, it's better to use `is not None`, rather than `!= None`

Your code

```
tree.right.left=Node(4)
tree.right.left=Node(5)
```

is probably the issue, try changing it to

```
tree.right.left=Node(4)
tree.right.right=Node(5)
```

Comment: I would add that in order to prevent this kind of error, just add `if root == None: return 0` in the first line of the evaluate function

Comment: If `root is None` is true, the tree doesn't correspond to a valid expression and can't be evaluated. An exception is more appropriate than providing a meaningless default value.